# Basis of a Z-module

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, modules

I *think* I might know how to start this problem but I'm not sure how to finish. Here is the statement:

> Determine a basis for the ℤ-module of integer solutions to the following system of equations:
>
> $4x + 7y + 2z = 0$
>
> $2x + 4y + 6z = 0$

This is how I was planning on proceeding. First consider the matrix:

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
4 & 7 & 2 \\
2 & 4 & 6 \end{array} \right)$

This represents the system. We can now put this matrix into Smith Normal Form using integer row and column operations. Doing this we get:

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \end{array} \right)$

We know this is in SNF because the only nonzero entries are on the diagonal and 1 divides 2 divides 0.

Now I'm having trouble interpreting this matrix though. $z$ should be a free variable, but that's all I'm getting from this. Could anyone give me some hints or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like there's a typo in your post.  The leading $2$ in the second row of the coefficient matrix doesn't agree with the leading $1$ in the second equation in the system.

Comment: Thank you! I just made the change. There was supposed to be a 2 in the original problem statement

Comment: How about solving over $\mathbb{R}$ first, and then restricting your attention to the integer solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Dividing the second row by $2$ gives you
$$x=-2y-3z$$
while taking $2\cdot \mbox{second row} - \mbox{first row}$ gives you
$$y=-10z$$
so that $x=17z$.

So your space solution is generated by $(17,-10,1)$, which is also a $\Bbb{Z}$-basis of the space.